# how to use outer-join with a where clause in an empty Table

Tags: sql, where-clause, outer-join

Hi I need to know how to get a result from an query (*which connects 2 tables with a outer join*) even if my where-clause which points in an empty table get's no result.

Example:

How the result currently looks [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a96a/2).
How the result should looks like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a96a/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Outer Join for this example dont use WHERE clause as it treats it as an inner join.

so instead just say AND instead of where

```
SELECT *
FROM FilledTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN EmptyTable 
ON FilledTable.Id = EmptyTable.RefFilledTableId
and EmptyTable.Value = 5
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a96a/9

Comment: Turst me i was in the same boat as you a while ago until someone pointed out, outer-joins generally shouldn't use Where clauses as there treated as inner joins....i was suprised hehe